# UIWebView - Local HTML Faster Load

Tags: performance, uiwebview, lag

I'm trying to figure out how to make a local HTML file load faster on iPad. The issue I'm having is that when opening the local HTML file on PC/Mac it runs pretty smooth no lag, but when opening on the iPad is lags quite a bit. 
This could be due to the difference in performance etc.

But there must be a way to increase the speed of opening the local HTML.

Comment: Does it include Js code in HTML file?

Comment: yes it includes JS code in the HTML

Comment: Just make another file where all Js code exists. You will have two files ( sample.html and ex.js ). Before Loading Html file in UIWebview, Just replace some text from Html ( <!-- Js code here --> with Js string from ex.js) and then load it to HTML . It worked for me.

Comment: Could you possibly post a tutorial on the steps to take? I don't understand, do you mean in the actual HTML of the file? so instead of having the javascript at the end put it in the front?